# How the RecommenderNet model works

Tags: python, keras, recommender-system

I'm newbie to collaborative filtering based recommendation, I have some questions about collaborative filtering when using keras' RecommenderNet model

- The RecommenderNet model uses Item-based collaborative filtering recommendations, right? User ratings for products do not affect the results of the recommendation process?
- If when using the model after training, a new product needs a minimum number of reviews for the product so that the model can work as expected.
- I came across an article on kaggle where they use 100 embedding_size instead of 50 embedding_size as in the model from the keras homepage. For my needs, 100 products with 1870 reviews and 27 users are often used by many embeddings. Default embedding will be optimal